# Data send through a port

Tags: http, post, web, get, port

My reuirement is to know the requests that are send from my computer while interaction in web. More specifically, when I communicate with different services in web, we share data. I need to know the data used in the transaction.

Can you let me know name of any application that can help me to do the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for WireShark:

http://www.wireshark.org/

It captures all data that goes through the select ethernet device, which can be a lot, but it also provides the ability to filter out almost anything to reduce the noise.